# Sending data back to AJAX function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple AJAX request which sends data to a PHP and the PHP sends some sucess data back to the AJAX as usual. For example

```
var firstvalue = xxx;
var secondvalue = xxx2;
```

AJAX

```
$.post("some.php",{value1 : firstvalue, value2 : secondvalue}, function(data){
    if(data) {
        alert(data);
    } else {
        alert("An error occurred.");
    }
});
```

PHP (*some.php*)

```
$id = S_GET['someid'];
$impdata = $_GET['somegettabledata']
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];

if (value1 === value2) {
    /* 
    This is my problem I want to echo id and impdata 
    but I don't know how to pass both of them
    */
    echo "...";
} else {
    echo "Error.";
}
```

So how can I have both the id and impdata in that data sent back from PHP? Sorry if this comes across as stupid.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP:

```
echo json_encode( array(
    'id' => $id,
    'impdata' => $impdata
));
```

In javascript you will need to parse the json string:

```
function(data){
    var myData = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(myData.id); //other notation: myData['id']
    alert(myData.impdata); //other notation: myData['impdata']
}
```

JSON parser can be found at the bottom of the following page: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: if you are using JQuery, you also can use jQuery.parseJSON(data) function instead of JSON.parse(data)

Answer (score 1):

You can return json response and read it back with JS:

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array('id' => $id, 'impdata' => $impdata));
```

JS:

```
alert(data['id']);
alert(data['impdata']);
```